# TWordApplication in Delphi 2010-XE

Tags: delphi, ms-word

Is there any in modern Delphi versions? (I've seen TWordApplication in Delphi 7)

Usually I use CreateComObject, but maybe there are more convenient/powerful ways, supporting Word 2007/2010?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You should enable already installed `Microsoft Office <version> Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components`, 
where `<version>` is your installed Office version identifier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got only XP Sample with Office 2010 installed. Is there anything newer?

Comment: @Keeper, no. You have to import type-libraries and generate wrapper compoments yourself if you want to use newer interfaces. XP still works, tho.

Comment: If you try to use the newer interfaces then you run the risk of using a feature that isn't available on some of the older versions. Realistically you have to support Office 2003 as a baseline since it is still, and will be for some time, very widely used.

Comment: @David Heffernan, it is *baseline* only de-facto, because Borland just stopped keeping it up to date (bankruptcy, restructurinsation, etc). There is nothing sacred in code from *official* sources (cf. [mis]types from system.pas :) as opposed to *home-made*. There were two releases since Office XP, its time to move forward.

Comment: @user I didn't make myself clear. If you use Office 2007 specific interfaces then your code will fail in 2003. If you import new type libraries you need to import the lowest common denominator which in my view should be no later than 2003. Unless of course you want all your users to abandon you for another product!!

Comment: @David Heffernan, my point was - why not Office 2000? 98? Where to stop when being ultimately backward-compatible? My suggestion was based on the fact OP wants modern COM servers.

Comment: @user No, OP asked for support for Office 2007/2010. Older COM interfaces are supported on newer versions of Office.

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light: Only two months ago we had a client that had problems with Word 97!! and our software (the fix was easy though). So there are still users with Office 97. I think a good rule is: take the components of the lowest Office version that is still supported by Microsoft or take the components that at least support what you want to do. Just keep in mind the differences in file formats between Office versions < 2007 and >= 2007.

Comment: @The_Fox, ah, it was 97, not 98! I even forgot right name! :) IMO, your case with single user with *really* old Office is not representative. However, desired support level is entirely up to developer, someone wishes to support old ones, i'd say move forward. There is no way to establish best approach w/o studying target userbase. BTW, Office XP reached its EoL couple of days ago, 2003 reached EoS 2,5 yrs ago.

Comment: Yes, Office 97 users are very rare. It was only a simple problem, so we fixed it. I think the majority of our userbase uses Office 2003 and higher (based on errorreports). Extended support for 2003 ends in 2014. About moving forward: yes, you can tell that to your customers, but what reasons are there for them to move forward? Fancy new UI? IMO most users only use features that were already available in Word 97.

Answer (score 7):

`TWordApplication` is available in modern versions of Delphi in exactly the same was as it was in Delphi 7.  In my view it is easier to use early binding with `TWordApplication` than the late bound `CreateComObject` approach.